# rollup-plugin-postcss uses node-sass, node-sass is deprecated, does rollup-plugin-postcss work with sass

Tags: sass, rollup, node-sass, rollup-plugin-postcss

Am configuring rollup to create a library package. The
rollup-plugin-postcss uses node-sass, node-sass is deprecated and needs python to install, is there some way to make rollup-plugin-postcss work with the sass npm package?